# ¿Qué sucede con el puntero original luego de hacer realloc en uno temporal?

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que exige colocar/liberar y recolocar memoria de forma algo excesiva, pero tengo una duda con respecto al uso de la función `realloc(void *, size_t)`, tengo el siguiente código:

```
void Resize(void *ptr, size_t sz) {
    if (ptr == NULL || sz == 0) 
        return;                   /* No se ve afectado. */

    void *tmp = realloc(ptr, sz); /* Aquí sucede mi problema. */

    if (tmp == NULL) 
        return;                   /* No pasa nada en caso de NULL */

    /* Otra logica... */
}
```

En la línea: `void *tmp = realloc(ptr, sz);` mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Si luego de esta línea libero la memoria de `ptr` de la siguiente manera:

```
free(ptr);
```

¿El puntero `tmp` seguirá siendo válido y apuntará hacia la *nueva*^ dirección de memoria dada por `realloc`?

^: Digo nueva porque no sé si `realloc` funciona como `malloc` para dar direcciones de memoria al cambiarlas de tamaño.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si luego de esa línea liberas `ptr`, `tmp` dejará de ser válido. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int *ptr;
   int *tmp;

   ptr = malloc(128);
   tmp = realloc(ptr, 256);
   free(ptr);
   free(tmp);

   return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutar el código obtienes:

```
Error in `./test': double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000019cb010
```

`realloc` funciona como `malloc` si `ptr` es `NULL`. Si `size` es `0` entonces `realloc` funciona como `free`.

Aquí otro ejemplo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int *ptr;
   int *tmp;

   ptr = malloc(128);
   tmp = realloc(ptr, 256);

   printf("%p == %p\n", ptr, tmp);

   free(ptr);

   return 0;
}
```

Y verás que ambas direcciones son iguales.

Comment: Es decir, que ambos punteros apuntan hacia la mosma dirección de memoria?

Comment: Exacto, tú estás reasignando ptr y tmp apunta al mismo lugar. Edito la respuesta con otro ejemplo que lo evidencia.

Comment: @NaCl No necesariamente. `realloc` va a intentar reservar la memoria solicitada comenzando por la dirección original. Si hay espacio, sencillamente, incrementa el bunch de memoria y el puntero devuelto es el mismo que el entregado. Si no hay suficiente, busca otra localización de memoria diferente, moviendo los contenidos a la nueva dirección, liberando la memoria original, y devolviendo el puntero a la nueva dirección donde ahora están tus datos.

En tu caso, `ptr` debe ser ignorado, y liberarse `tmp`. Si liberas `ptr` después del `realloc`, y `realloc` ha movido el puntero... crash.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pero cuidado con el standard actual (C11): `realloc(..., 0)` ya no es sinónimo de `free`: _If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object_

Comment: Es una deuda ponerme al día con el standard. Muchas gracias por la aclaración Keine

Answer (score 2):

Las funciones para trabajar con memoria dinámica son:

- `malloc`: Esta función nos permite reservar un área de memoria del tamaño que deseemos.
- `calloc`: Similar a `malloc`. Además de reservar la memoria inicializa todos los bytes a 0.
- `realloc`: Intenta reubicar los datos en otra zona de memoria diferente acorde a los nuevos requisitos (estos nuevos requisitos pueden implicar una zona más grande o más pequeña).
- `free`: Esta función libera la memoria reservada con cualquiera de los tres métodos anteriores.

Un posible ejemplo de la implementación de `realloc` podría ser la siguiente:

```
void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size)
{
  // Si se indica tamaño 0 no se hace nada
  if( size == 0 )
    return ptr;

  void* newPtr = malloc(size);
  if( newPtr != NULL && ptr != NULL )
  {
    // Si hemos conseguido una nueva zona de memoria
    // Movemos los datos (si la nueva zona es más pequeña)
    // no podemos copiar toda la memoria)
    memcpy(newPtr,ptr,size);
    free(ptr);
  }

  return newPtr;
}
```

Es decir:

- Si se indica que el nuevo tamaño es 0 no se hace nada y la memoria no se libera
- Si no se puede reservar memoria, no se hace nada y la memoria no se libera
- Si la reserva se ha realizado y es más grande, se copia el contenido de la antigua memoria en la nueva y la vieja se libera
- Si la reserva se ha realizado y es más pequeña, se copia lo que quepa en la nueva memoria y la vieja se libera.

Dicho esto, si tu haces lo siguiente:

```
void* tmp = realloc(ptr, 256);
free(ptr);
```

El resultado será una de las siguientes posibilidades:

- Si `tmp==NULL`, estarás perdiendo la memoria original sin posibilidad de vuelta atrás.
- Si `tmp!=NULL`, estarás intentando liberar una zona de memoria que ya está liberada y eso suele provocar el cierre de la aplicación.

Y no parece que ninguna de estas opciones sea deseable.

Lo que tienes que hacer es reservar `free` para cuando realmente ya no necesites la memoria que estás utilizando. El siguiente ejemplo no tiene fugas de memoria:

```
void* tmp = realloc(NULL, 256); // (1)
void* tmp2 = realloc(tmp,100); // (2)
void* tmp3 = realloc(tmp2,150); //(3)
free(tmp3); //(4)
```

Y hace lo siguiente:

1. Hace una reserva de memoria de 256 bytes
2. Hace una reserva de memoria de 100 bytes y si la reserva es correcta copia los primeros 100 bytes de la memoria antigua y después libera la memoria antigua
3. Hace una reserva de memoria de 150 bytes, copia la memoria antigua en la nueva y después libera la memoria antigua
4. Libera la región de 150 bytes. Llegados a este punto no hay memoria reservada.

Comment: Transcribo del `man malloc` (conforme con C89 y C99): `if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not  NULL,  then  the  call  is equivalent to free(ptr)`.

Comment: No siempre se reserva nueva memoria para el nuevo apuntador. Primero se intenta redimensionar el bloque actual. The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.

Comment: @JuanManuel "_If new_size is zero, the behavior is implementation defined (null pointer may be returned (in which case the old memory block is not freed)_". Fuente: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: @FranciscoMendez implementar esa característica en el ejemplo de `realloc` no es trivial y podría complicar su lectura en exceso (aparte de que seguramente no sería un ejemplo portable). Intentaba ser simplemente un ejemplo didáctico

Comment: @eferion Estoy de acuerdo, de hecho tu ejemplo es bastante didáctico y muy claro, sólo creo que estás dejando de lado tal vez la característica más importante de realloc, es una simple opinión, tal vez podrías escribirla en forma similar a la respuesta en inglés. Considero quedaría completa y fácil de entender. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437482/how-realloc-work-actually-in-the-background